# Remove black bars on both left & right sides of an iframe video

Tags: html, css, iframe

I have an embedded video using iframe. But there are black bars on both left & right sides of the video, video original size is 2000 x 2000)

iframe currently display

[image]

html currently is:

```css
.iframe-video {
  display: block;
  margin: 20px auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30vh;
  overflow: none;
}
@media (max-width: 832px) {
  .iframe-video {
    width: 100%;
    height: 30vh;
    max-width: 80vw;
  }
}
```

```html
<article>

  <div class="article2">Food</div>
  <h2 class="h2a">Our New Menu is ready</h2>
  
  <iframe src="/video/menu.mp4" class="iframe-video" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="" title="post"></iframe>

  <p>Make your reservation ASAP!</p>

</article>
```

Any simple way I can remove the black bars on both sides?
I tried adding another <div> wrapper the current iframe and setting the padding-bottom. But seems not working.

Comment: The video is square and you've set the height to 30vh but the width at 100%. While we don't know enough to know what that is 100% of, it's possible it's rather large compared to 30vh. Any reason not to set the video element to square if the underlying video is square?

Comment: there is another <article> with another video, size 4096width, 2160height. So, don't know how to keep both iframe, but without the black side borders on left and right.   Thanks for answering my question.

Comment: If you need to accommodate two different video aspect ratios your example should show that. You can use images instead of videos for the demo.

Comment: I am not sure how to use an image for the demo of an iframe

Comment: Please update the code in your question to add a second video and explain that they have different aspect ratios.  If you want the height of both to be 30vh then try css width: 30vh on the first one and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

We can use the `aspect-ratio` CSS property to achieve the same result as [@EdgarAlexPoe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70851961/11361359) with less math.

CSS:

```
.video-container {
   aspect-ratio: 16/9;
 }
    
.video-container iframe {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="video-container">
  <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/dQw4w9WgXcQ" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/trevorleeman/pen/YzerBKa

Answer (score 0):

so the best way to make your video responsive without any black sidebars, is to nest your iframe within a parent div. You will make this parent container "hold" the video using `position: relative` with the iframe displaying using `position: absolute`. The key declaration for the parent element is `padding: 56.25%`. This keeps the elements to 16:9 ratio and will make your video responsive.

```
 .video-container { 
    position: relative; 
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
} 

.video-container iframe,
.video-container object,
.video-container embed { 
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/EdgarAlexPoe/gak5cfsh/3/

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have tried this method but not working. On the same page I have 2 iframes, 1 of 2000x20000, the other size 4096width x 2160height, so I am not sure how to keep both iframe without making black sidebars, thanks!